# Windows server 2008 R2 Service error 1053

Tags: windows, service

I have problems with starting service.
Service is designed to sending emails from SQL db.
Service developed by company which I work in.
I used to use it in implementation for other customers and until now I had no errors so application files should be alright.

I cant bear with problems during my implementation.
I have tried to run this on my customer 2 different Windows Server 2008 R2

After trying to start service, **IMMEDIATELY** receiving following error:
1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

**I have tried to repair reinstall:**

.Net framework 1.0 / 1.1 (with sp1)

.Net framework 2.0 and others

**Checked registry:**

I had set up registry key "ServicesPipeTimeout" on 120 seconds. (service fails immediately)

**Checked services:**

DCOM Server Process Launcher - running

Windows Event Log - running

**Service proporties:**
Logon tab:

Unchecked - Allow service to interact with dekstop.

Tested also:  Administrator account / Local account.

.

**Folders:**
C:\WINDOWS\Registration  (full control for Administrators/System, read for All)

Checked also:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/886695

In Event log theres only information about Service Timeout.

Any other proposals ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

Problem was caused by using polish char in service XML configuration value.
example:

wrong

```
 <add key="displayName" value="Obsługa" />
```

correct

```
 <add key="displayName" value="Obsluga" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the .EXE-file from DOS-Box, or use Tools like Depends to find out if all necessary DLLs are installed.

Comment: I have checked it in the green border there's dll's missing on my system too. But even without it service works properly http://oi61.tinypic.com/hv9tmc.jpg